# make a div move after another is clicked

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make something move when a link is clicked. I cannot seem to get them to work together. Anyone know how to do so.

### CSS

```
#drop:focus #login_dropdown {
    margin-top: 0;
}
#login_dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="login_dropdown" class="clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login_dropdown_header">
             <h1>Login</h1>

        </div>
        <form action="login.php" method="post" id="login_form" class="clearfix">
            <ul id="login_reg">
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </li>
                <li> <a href="register.php">Register</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul> <a href="index.php"><li>Home</li></a>
 <a href="ledge_base.php"><li>Knowledge Base</li></a>
 <a href="faq.php"><li>FAQ</li></a>

                <!--<a href="#"><li>Teach</li></a>--> <a href="contact.php"><li>Contact</li></a>
 <a href="#"><li id="drop">Login/Register</li></a>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Anyways, I am trying to get `#login_dropdown` to change its margin to 0 when `#drop` is clicked on. But after clicking on it nothing happens. Can someone help me?

Comment: `<a href="index.php"><li>Home</li></a>` should instead be `<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

```
#drop:focus #login_dropdown {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Looking at that CSS - I see your logic is that "When `#drop` is the focus, set `margin-top` to zero for `#login_dropdown`"

The problem is `#login_dropdown` isn't a descendant of `#drop`, it's an ascendant. There currently is no ascendant selector in CSS so you'll likely need to use javascript (or jQuery) to accomplish this.

---

Though it has been put forth in CSS Selectors Level 4 Spec - More info: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/21/sneak-peek-future-selectors-level-4/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/497604